# How to solarize an image

Tags: python, image, pixel

I am trying to make a function that will solarize an image, but before I can do that I need to know **how** to solarize an image.

According to Wiki:

"the image recorded on a negative or on a photographic print is wholly or partially reversed in tone. Dark areas appear light or light areas appear dark"

I am running a python framework which allows me to access  all the pixels in an image and their RGB values. From there does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's some good information on how that effect is digitally recreated](http://courses.washington.edu/hypertxt/cgi-bin/book/pmontage/solarized.html)

Comment: No, actually I am running a python framework which allows me to access  all the pixels in an image and their RGB values.

Comment: Changed the answer. You need to be more specific with what your needs are and how you have attempted to accomplish this.